# Найти файлы в Ubuntu, измененные от 30 минут до суток

Tags: файлы, bash

Необходимо найти все файлы, которые были изменены от 30 мин до 24 часов. Нашел подобную конструкцию в днях:

```
$ find ~ mtime 0,0208 -mtime -1 -daystart
```

0,0208(3) - это 30 мин от суток, но период в скрипт не запишешь и получается неточное время поиска. Пробовал сменить предикат "daystart" на "hourstart", но find такой не знает. Как можно перевести поиск в часы\минуты?

Comment: так а так не работает: `find ~ -mtime 0,0208 -mtime -1`?

Comment: @ipatev_nn Работает, но, как я уже раньше написал, остается небольшой период 0.000(3), который выдает не совсем корректные варианты

Comment: Чому бы не -mmin?

Comment: @user_587  `$ find ~ -mmin 30 -mmin -1440`  выдает неверный результат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
find ~ -type f -mtime -1 ! -mmin -30 -print
```

`-type f` - ищем тока файлы

`-mtime -1` - которые менялись за последний день

`! -mmin -30` - но исключить последние пол часа